# Is there a way using powershell or Graph API to obtain information about the creator of application in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

Is there a way using powershell or Graph API to obtain information about the user who created or registered an application in Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Add application' and targetResources/any(c:c/id eq 'application object id').
```

Then look at the intitedBy property in the response.

Comment: It won't give me the information about the user who has registered the application in Azure AD. This API will give owner information of the application which can be different from the actual user who created/registered the app in Azure AD

Comment: @Rajat sorry,I don't see your problem too well...,i have update my answer.:)

Comment: Thanks Zhou, this helps. Just wanted to confirm, by default we can get the audit logs for last 30 days only, correct. So with this API will get result of only those apps that got created in last 30 days and not before that date. Correct?

Comment: @Rajat Yes. This API can only access the data that has not expired.

Comment: So, is there any other alternative to achieve it?